# Central extension gives a gerbe over stack

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, stacks, gerbes

Consider a central extension of Lie groups $1\rightarrow S^1\rightarrow \hat{G}\xrightarrow{\pi} G\rightarrow 1$.

I understand that this mean $\pi:\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ is a surjective homomorphism of Lie groups (not sure if this has to be submersion) and that $S^1\subseteq Z(\hat{G})$. There is a local section $\sigma:U\rightarrow \hat{G}$ such that $\pi\circ \sigma=1_U$ where $U$ is an open nbd of $1\in G$. Correct me if I am missing some conditions.

Let $X$ be a manifold with an action of $G$ on it. Then we have the notion of [quotient stack](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319038/motivation-for-definition-of-quotient-stack) $[X/G]$.

There is an action of $\hat{G}$ on $X$ given by $(\hat{g},x)\mapsto \pi(\hat{g})\cdot x$.

We can then consider the quotient stack $[X/\hat{G}]$.

Given a manifold $Y$, objects of  $[X/G](Y)$ are pairs $(P\rightarrow Y,P\rightarrow X)$ where $P\rightarrow Y$ is a principal $G$ bundle and $P\rightarrow X$ is a $G$-equivariant space (see that $G$ acts on $P$ and $X$).

> "As locally any map $T\rightarrow G$ can be lifter to $\tilde{G}$", the map of stacks $[X/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [X/G]$ is a gerbe over stack.

I see that, locally any map $\theta: T\rightarrow G$ can be lifted to $\hat{G}$. As there is a section $\sigma:U\rightarrow \hat{G}$, we can consider $\theta^{-1}(U)\xrightarrow{\theta} U\xrightarrow{\sigma} \hat{G}$ and $\pi\circ (\sigma\circ \theta)=\theta$. Thus, any map $\theta:T\rightarrow G$ can be locally lifted to $\hat{G}$. But, I am not able to see why this imply $[X/\tilde{G}]\rightarrow [X/G]$ is a gerbe over stack.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: You can consider the special case of $X=pt$, since the example you give is pulled back along $[X/G] \to [pt/G]$, and the pullback of a gerbe is a gerbe.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I am getting confused with English ... You are asking to take $X=pt$ and then saying consider $[X/G]\rightarrow [pt/G]$... Are you saying consider the obvious map of stacks $[X/G]\rightarrow [*/G]$ and pull back  $[*/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [*/G]$ along $[X/G]\rightarrow [*/G]$ to get $[X/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [X/G]$?? As $[*/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [*/G]$ is a gerbe over stack, so is the pull back $[X/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [X/G]$?? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Then, also, it should be easier to see why the stack $[pt/\hat{G}]$ of principal $\hat{G}$-bundles is a gerbe over $[pt/G]$. Given any $X\to [pt/G]$, that is, a principal $G$-bundle $P\to X$, there is a cover $U\to X$ such that $U\to X \to [pt/G]$ lifts to $[pt/\hat{G}]$: just take a trivialising cover for $P$. Thus $[pt/\pi]$ is an epimorphism of stacks. A similar type of thinking—unwinding the definition of the stack in terms of bundles—will help to show that $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/\hat{G}] \times_{[pt/G]} [pt/\hat{G}]$ is also an epimorphism.

Comment: In response to your comment: yes.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ok. Thanks for the clarification :) First I have to prove that $[*/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [*/G]$ is a gerbe over stack and then prove that pull back (fiber product) of gerbe over stack is a gerbe over stack (it may be obvious but I did not prove yet).. It looks like it has nothing to do with central extension... Any morphism of Lie groups $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ such that there is a local section $U\rightarrow \hat{G}$ should give a gerbe over stack $[*/\hat{G}]\rightarrow [*/G]$... Is that  the case?

Comment: yes ........  :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks, I am trying.. You said "just take a trivialising cover for $P$." I tried with same technique before but I could not succeed.. I will try one more time.... :)

Comment: Any trivial $G$-bundle $U\times G$ has a canonical lift to a principal $\hat{G}$-bundle :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts that’s true.. just the bundle $U\times \hat{G}\rightarrow U$.. I tried previously also the same thing but left at a point where I thought there is no hope.. yesterday night I tried and it worked to some extent.. I did not wanted to say anything in hurry.. so written down in detail.. it seems like I need to assume $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ is a principal $S^1$ bundle.. if you want to see what I have done, I can show.. How much you are sure that it has nothing to do with $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ is a principal $S^1$ bundle? It does not seem to work for any morphism of Lie groups..

Comment: I woke up just now (10 am for me... I worked till 5 am, thanks to you :D.. you said there is a hope, so I worked harder.. though i did not get the result in the generality you said but I got something)... I will write down after some time if you want to see @DavidRoberts

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think what you said is true... I am able to see that given a morphism of Lie groups $\theta:G\rightarrow H$, the corresponding map of stacks $[*/G]\rightarrow [*/H]$ is a gerbe over stack (epimorphism for sure, I checked it just now and I do not need the condition that it is a principal bundle. For principal bundle it is true but it is not necessary)... This seems very surprising.. Why did Heinloth mentioned that there is some central extension $S^1\rightarrow \hat{G}\rightarrow G$??

Comment: have you checked that $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/\hat{G}] \times_{[pt/G]} [pt/\hat{G}]$ is an epimorphism?

Comment: It is true that $B\hat{G}\times_{BG}B\hat{G}=B(\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G})$ (as $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ is a submersion, the pull back $\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$ is an embedded submanifold of $\hat{G}\times \hat{G}$.. It is also true that $\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$ is a subgroup (closed under multiplication and inverse). Any subgroup that is an embedded submanifold is a Lie subgroup. So, $\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$ is a Lie subgroup of $\hat{G}\times\hat{G}$)... @DavidRoberts

Comment: Now, the diagonal map $B\hat{G}\rightarrow B\hat{G}\times_{BG}B\hat{G}$ would then be simply arising from $\hat{G}\rightarrow \hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$.. and I have seen that for any morpshim of Lie groups $G\rightarrow H$, $BG\rightarrow BH$ is an epimorphism.. So, for $\hat{G}\rightarrow \hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$ the corresponding map $B\hat{G}\rightarrow B(\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G})=B\hat{G}\times_{BG}B\hat{G}$ is an epimorphsim.. Thus, $B\hat{G}\rightarrow BG$ is a gerbe over stack. I am not able to see the flaw. @DavidRoberts

Comment: @DavidRoberts As $BG$ is trivially a stack (gerbe for some people), the obvious map of stacks $BG\rightarrow BH$ coming from a morphism of Lie groups should be a gerbe over stack... Does this sentence make some sense? I am having a feeling that $BG\rightarrow BH$ is a gerbe over stack for any morphism of Lie groups $G\rightarrow H$... SAme thing that you have said...

Comment: "It is true that..." this uses the fact that  $\hat{G}\to G$ is surjective. || "$BG\to BH$ is a gerbe..." well, in the previous comment you used surjectivity, so it can't be for arbitrary homomorphisms. Take the case that $H=U(1)$ and $G=\langle e \rangle = pt$ and see if $pt \to pt\times_{BU(1)} pt$ is an epimorphism of stacks: it is not, since $pt\times_{BU(1)} pt$ is just the stack associated to the underlying manifold of $U(1)$. Then the diagonal map (by Yoneda) is precisely that arising from the ordinary map of manifolds, $e\colon \pt \to U(1)$—not surjective!

Comment: Yes yes, definitely.. I wanted to say for surjective submersion... @DavidRoberts is there a quick proof for the fact that $B\hat{G}\times_{BG}B\hat{G}\cong B(\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G})$ given that I know $\hat{G}\rightarrow G$ is a surjective submersion..

Comment: See my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/321296/4177, I don't know any simpler proof off the top of my head.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ok, Ok. I will work on that...Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to understand your last comment for surjectivity..  You are saying that, if $G\rightarrow H$ is not surjective then, $BG\rightarrow BG\times_{BH}BG$ need not be an **epimorphism** You said to consider $\left<e \right>\rightarrow U(1)$ and consider $\left<e\right>\rightarrow \left<e\right>\times _{BU(1)}\left<e\right>$.. This is same as the $\left<e\right>\rightarrow U(1)$.. you said this is not surjective. That is ok, but we do not need it to be surjective.. we want it to be an epimorphism.. Am I misunderstanding something.we need to look for epimor., not surjective...@DavidRoberts

Comment: Epimorphism of manifolds = surjective function

Comment: It is true that given manifolds $M,N$ if $\underline{M}\rightarrow \underline{N}$ is an epimorphism then $M\rightarrow N$ is a surjective submersion... I do not think it holds for the case of Lie groups... I have proved, given any morphism of Lie groups $G\rightarrow H$, associated map $BG\rightarrow BH$ is an epimorphism... I can show you if you permit me to show.. @DavidRoberts

Comment: _Then the diagonal map (by Yoneda) is precisely that arising from the ordinary map of manifolds_ (so not as a Lie group).

Comment: @DavidRoberts I do not know **why** I am misunderstanding like this... thanks.. I will spend some more time...

Comment: Perhaps I should have written $S^1$ instead of $U(1)$. It's meant to just be a map stacks representable by manifolds.

Comment: Ok :) @DavidRoberts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, $[X/\hat{G}] \to [X/G]$ is the pullback of $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/G]$ along the canonical map $[X/G] \to [pt/G]$, so it suffices to show that $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/G]$ is a gerbe. Since every principal $G$-bundle is locally trivial, it can be locally lifted to a principal $\hat{G}$-bundle, which is another way of saying that $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/G]$ is an epimorphism of stacks. Using the fact that $\hat{G}\to G$ is surjective, then there is an equivalence of stacks 
$$
[pt/\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}] \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} [pt/\hat{G}]\times_{[pt/G]}[pt/\hat{G}]
$$
Thus the diagonal $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/\hat{G}]\times_{[pt/G]}[pt/\hat{G}]$ is equivalent to $[pt/\hat{G}] \to [pt/\hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}]$, induced by the diagonal homomorphism $\hat{G} \to \hat{G}\times_G\hat{G}$. Such a map of stacks is an epimorphism by the same argument as before, and so we are done.

Comment: You mean “which is another way of saying” when you said “which is **not** another way of saying “